# React app no longer compiling after running the eject script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, compiler-errors

I have run the eject command on my react application, as I needed to override the webpack.config.js file. For some reason when I try to run the app it is now failing to compile and is outputting the following error in the terminal. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
 D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\scripts\start.js:11
[0]   throw err;
[0]   ^
[0]
[0] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')
[0]     at Compilation.createModuleAssets (D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:4483:25)
[0]     at D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3052:13
[0]     at D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3277:6
[0]     at Object.eachLimit (D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3461:14)
[0]     at runIteration (D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3206:13)
[0]     at Compilation._runCodeGenerationJobs (D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3281:3)
[0]     at D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3037:12
[0]     at D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3277:6
[0]     at D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
[0]     at done (D:\Software Projects\Repos\ipfs-archive\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')
updating webpack.config.js may have altered the code path for building.  What does the webpack.config.js look like?

Comment: (For future reference [rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts) will allow you to modify the webpack config without ejecting.)

Comment: It is simply the way it comes when running the eject script, with the addition of adding NodePolyfillPlugin